# Is ipython or numpy secretly parallelizing matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython-parallel

So the case is the following:
I wanted to compare the runtime for a matrix multiplication
with ipython parallel and just running on a single core.

Code for normal execution:

```
import numpy as np
n = 13
dim_1, dim_2, dim_3, dim_4 = 2**n, 2**n, 2**n, 2**n
A = np.random.random((dim_1, dim_2))
B = np.random.random((dim_3, dim_4))
start = timeit.time.time()
C = np.matmul(A,B)
dur = timeit.time.time() - start
```

well this amounts to about 24 seconds on my notebook
If I do the same thing trying to parallize it.
I start four engines using: ipcluster start -n 4 (I have 4 cores).
Then I run in my notebook:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
c = Client()
dview = c.load_balanced_view()
%px import numpy
def pdot(view_obj, A_mat, B_mat):
    view_obj['B'] = B
    view_obj.scatter('A', A)
    view_obj.execute('C=A.dot(B)')
    return view_obj.gather('C', block=True)
start = timeit.time.time()
pdot(dview, A, B)
dur1 = timeit.time.time() - start
dur1
```

which takes approximately 34 seconds. 
When I view in the system monitor I can see, that in both
cases all cores are used. In the parallel case there seems to
be an overhead where they aren't on 100 % usage (I suppose that's
the part where they get scattered across the engines).
In the non parallel part immediately all cores are on 100 % usage.
This surprises me as I always thought python was intrinsically 
run on a single core.

Would be happy if somebody has more insight into this.

Comment: Python code is typically executed on a single core, but `matmul` calls compiled code which *can* execute on multiple cores. In this case `matmul` may call on BLAS/LAPACK to compute the dot product if so configured on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think that is probably what it is as I have BLAS/LAPACK installed. Is there a way to reward people for useful comments?