# Is numpy matmul parallelized and how to stop it?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

Looking at the resource monitor during the execution of my script I noticed that all the cores of my PC were working, even if I did not implement any form of multiprocessing. Trying to pinpoint the cause, I discovered that the code is parallelized when using `numpy`'s `matmult` (or, as in the example below, the binary operator `@`).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10,500)
B = np.random.rand(500,50000)
while True:
    _ = A @ B
```

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262243/is-ipython-or-numpy-secretly-parallelizing-matrix-multiplication) it looks like the reason is that `numpy` invokes `BLAS/LAPACK` routines that are indeed parallelized.

Despite being nice that my code runs faster and uses all available resources, this is causing me troubles when I submit my code on a shared cluster managed by `PBS` queue manager. Together with the cluster IT manager, we noticed that even if I ask for N CPUs on a cluster node, `numpy` was still spawning a number of threads equal to the number of CPUs on the node.

This resulted in the node to be overloaded, as I was using more CPUs than those assigned to me.

Is there a way to "control" this behaviour and tell `numpy` how many CPUs it can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `threadpoolctl`. See the [README](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl#setting-the-maximum-size-of-thread-pools) for details. Before using, I recommend to have a look at the ["known limitations"](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl#known-limitations) section, though.

Citation from that README

> Python helpers to limit the number of threads used in the
>   threadpool-backed of common native libraries used for scientific
>   computing and data science (e.g. BLAS and OpenMP).
>
> Fine control of the underlying thread-pool size can be useful in
>   workloads that involve nested parallelism so as to mitigate
>   oversubscription issues.

Code snippet from that README

```py
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_limits
import numpy as np


with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api='blas'):
    # In this block, calls to blas implementation (like openblas or MKL)
    # will be limited to use only one thread. They can thus be used jointly
    # with thread-parallelism.
    a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
    a_squared = a @ a
```